# Why does opening an undef not fail?

Tags: perl, undef

This code dies as I expect it to:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, "<", "" or die $!;
```

But this does not:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, "<", undef or die $!;
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 17):

The [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) function has lots of little quirks, this is one of them:

> As a special case the three-argument form with a read/write mode and
>   the third argument being "undef":
>
> ```
> open(my $tmp, "+>", undef) or die ...
> ```
>
> opens a filehandle to an anonymous temporary file. Also using "+<"
>   works for symmetry, but you really should consider writing something
>   to the temporary file first. You will need to seek() to do the
>   reading.

Although, as ysth notes in the comments, the documentation strongly suggests that this should only happen for "+<" and ">+" modes.  I believe this is the code that implements the behavior.  It does not check the mode.  I do not know if this is a bug or not, but will report back after talking to P5P.

```
PerlIO *
PerlIO_openn(pTHX_ const char *layers, const char *mode, int fd,
             int imode, int perm, PerlIO *f, int narg, SV **args)
{
    if (!f && narg == 1 && *args == &PL_sv_undef) {
        if ((f = PerlIO_tmpfile())) {
            if (!layers || !*layers)
                layers = Perl_PerlIO_context_layers(aTHX_ mode);
            if (layers && *layers)
                PerlIO_apply_layers(aTHX_ f, mode, layers);
        }
    }
```

Apparently, the documentation was [fixed in blead perl in November](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commitdiff/32458de9a4322bd2e66c525d33720a42df7e0b56):

```
diff --git a/pod/perlfunc.pod b/pod/perlfunc.pod
index 18bb4654e1..1e32cca6dd 100644
--- a/pod/perlfunc.pod
+++ b/pod/perlfunc.pod
@@ -4405,9 +4405,9 @@ argument being L<C<undef>|/undef EXPR>:

     open(my $tmp, "+>", undef) or die ...

-opens a filehandle to an anonymous temporary file.  Also using C<< +< >>
-works for symmetry, but you really should consider writing something
-to the temporary file first.  You will need to
+opens a filehandle to a newly created empty anonymous temporary file.
+(This happens under any mode, which makes C<< +> >> the only useful and
+sensible mode to use.)  You will need to
 L<C<seek>|/seek FILEHANDLE,POSITION,WHENCE> to do the reading.

 Perl is built using PerlIO by default.  Unless you've
```

Comment: yes, this is what is happening, but the doc seems to be wrong, since this is clearly not a read/write mode

Comment: the read/write mode is `+>` AND the third argument is `undef`. It is just worded poorly

Comment: Hmm, good point @ysth, I glossed over it in my anger.  I read it as read or write mode, but it is pretty explicit that it is for read+write or write+read modes.  So, either this is a bug or poorly documented.